# Call of Duty: Ghosts, stuck in "No Man's Land"

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

As the title says, I am on the mission *No Man's Land*. Just after we take control of Riley for the first time we have two guards, one of which we have to kill, the one watering the grass, Hesh or Logan kill the other one which we lure out.

In my case when I lure out one of the guards they don't kill him and I get killed every time. Even if I kill him by chance, the sniper on the roof isn't shot by Hesh or Logan. I can kill the other two guards by luring one of them but the sniper always remains and thus I cannot move further in the game. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Hesh or Logan always kill the sniper for me.  I have completed the mission on 3 different platforms, and it always happens this way.

Without seeing what you do, I can only guess that you get spotted or start barking before the sniper is killed.  Try waiting in the house without being spotted, look at the sniper and then wait 10 or so seconds.  Hesh/Logan should say something like "I got him".  After, they take the shot.  I am pretty sure the sniper's outline turns orange when the others decide they are going to take care of him for you.

In reference to the 2 enemies previous, I always kill the first guy and then bark to lure the other guy out.  I am never fast enough to kill this second guy (Hesh/Logan always kill him for me).

General tips for not getting spotted is to stay in the grass, and attack from behind.  Using the bark draws enemies to you, so maybe move around to the side/back of an enemies path after using it.

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to have Riley run up the side ramp.

There is like a hill.
Next, you bark to lure the guy out, run to the bottom of the hill and kill him.
After that, you run in to kill the other guard inside while having Logan kill the sniper.

At least, that's how I did it.

Comment: Not working, and to continue game I had to get a save file. I tried that mission around 20-30 times, with the same result every time.